# How to trigger daily DAG run at midnight local time instead of midnight UTC time

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm in the UTC+4 timezone, so when Airflow triggers the nightly ETLs, it's already 4:00AM here. How can I tell Airflow to trigger the run for day ds already on day ds-1 at 20:00, but with ds=ds?

Per the docs it's highly recommended to keep all servers on UTC, so that's why I'm looking for an application-level solution.

EDIT: a hacky solution is to define it to run everyday at 20:00PM, so the "previous" day, but then use `tomorrow_ds` instead of `ds` in the job. But that still looks weird on the Airflow UI, because that's going to show the UTC execution time.

Answer (score 14):

Schedule interval can also be a "cron expression" which means you can easily run it at 20:00 UTC. That coupled with "user_defined_filters" means you can, with a bit of trickery get the behaviour you want:

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime

import pytz
tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Dubai')


def localize_utc_tz(d):
    return tz.fromutc(d)

default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime(2017, 11, 8),
}
dag = DAG(
    'plus_4_utc',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='0 20 * * *',
    user_defined_filters={
        'localtz': localize_utc_tz,
    },
)
task = BashOperator(
        task_id='task_for_testing_file_log_handler',
        dag=dag,
        bash_command='echo UTC {{ ts }}, Local {{ execution_date | localtz }} next {{ next_execution_date | localtz }}',
)
```

This outputs:

> UTC 2017-11-08T20:00:00, Local 2017-11-09 00:00:00+04:00 next 2017-11-10 00:00:00+04:00

You'll have to be careful about the "types" of variables you use. For instance `ds` and `ts` are strings, not datetime objects which means the filter wont work on them

Comment: This doesn't do much for the times shown in the Airflow UI sadly :(

Comment: A core dev on the Airflow team has started work on fixing this properly meaning you'd be able to do `start_date = datetime(2017, 1, 1, tzinfo=“Europe/Amsterdam”)`. See https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/2781 to track this. It will likely be in Airflow 1.10

Comment: Airflow 1.10 is out, but actually it does not help since the execution_date in template remains in UTC unless you convert it by yourself...  https://airflow.apache.org/timezone.html#templates  which are you're doing in answer. Really don't know why they introduced timezone awareness DAG but only works for triggering the DAG, the rest is still work like before.

Comment: Yeah, the UI doesn't display things right (because the core of Airflow operates in UTC) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-2805 is the ticket for updating the timezones displaye din the UI

Comment: this worked for me:
tz = pendulum.timezone("Asia/Tehran") 
def local_ds(d):
    return tz.fromutc(d).date()

Answer (score 3):

I had come up with same problem. I have daily, hourly, half-an hour jobs.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pendulum

local_tz = pendulum.timezone("Asia/Calcutta")

args = {
    'owner': 'ganesh',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 3, 25, tzinfo=local_tz),
    'email': ['abcd@test.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='test1',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='30 00 * * *'
    )

first_date = BashOperator(
    task_id='first_date'
    ,
    bash_command='date'
    , dag=dag, env=None, output_encoding='utf-8')

second_date = BashOperator(
    task_id='second_date'
    ,
    bash_command='echo date'
    , dag=dag, env=None, output_encoding='utf-8')

first_date >> second_date
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a python util that rewrite your tz-based schedule into UTC?
https://github.com/bloomberg/tzcron/blob/master/tzcron.py

EDIT: there is recent commit that makes Airflow Timezone aware:
https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/commit/f1ab56cc6ad3b9419af94aaa333661c105185883

Comment: commit from 28-oct made airlfow timezone aware