# Emails with Airflow

Tags: email, smtp, airflow

Do I have to do any additional setup in order to get apache-airflow to send me emails on task failure. I have the following in my config file (unchanged from the defaults):

```
[email]
email_backend = airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp


[smtp]
# If you want airflow to send emails on retries, failure, and you want to use
# the airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp function, you have to configure an
# smtp server here
smtp_host = localhost
smtp_starttls = True
smtp_ssl = False
# Uncomment and set the user/pass settings if you want to use SMTP AUTH
# smtp_user = airflow
# smtp_password = airflow
smtp_port = 25
smtp_mail_from = airflow@example.com
```

and in my task I have

```
'email': ['my.email@domain.co.uk'],
'email_on_failure': True,
```

But it is not sending me emails when the task fails.

I have seen this question: [How do I setup Airflow's email configuration to send an email on errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44573923/how-do-i-setup-airflows-email-configuration-to-send-an-email-on-errors) but I didn't really understand what actions to take from it. I'm just looking for the basics on what needs to be done before airflow will send emails. Do I have to configure my own smtp server or should it work out the box?

I'm running apache-airflow 1.9.0 on CentOS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need your own SMTP service. We use Mailgun and Sendgrid internally and it works pretty well. You'll just need to change those lines in your `.cfg` with your credentials, restart airflow, and you should be good to go!

Comment: Thanks, do you have an opinion on what the easiest (free?) SMTP service to set-up is? I'll take a look at Mailgun and at Sendgrid now. Do I need both?

Comment: I believe Mailgun gives you 10K emails for free to start. Either one should work - you should only need one.

Comment: I have set up an account with Mailgun and I have the [swaks example](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html#send-via-smtp) from their site working in my terminal. Is their anything else I still need to do to get this working with airflow besides filling in my username and password? Must I change the `smtp_host` in the airflow config file to be `smtp.mailgun.org`?

Comment: Yeah I think you'll have to do that - along with the rest of the credentials. Shoudn't be anything outside of that

Answer (score 2):

There is a Sendgrid subpackage available in airflow contrib if you prefer to use Sendgrid
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/utils/sendgrid.py

And then just follow the instructions mentioned in the link.

```
    0. include sendgrid subpackage as part of your Airflow installation, e.g.,
    pip install apache-airflow[sendgrid] 

    1. update [email] backend in airflow.cfg, i.e.,
    [email]
    email_backend = airflow.contrib.utils.sendgrid.send_email

    2. configure Sendgrid specific environment variables at all Airflow instances:
    SENDGRID_MAIL_FROM={your-mail-from}
    SENDGRID_API_KEY={your-sendgrid-api-key}.
```

Comment: The email backend looks like it will be updated in Airflow 2.0 or thereabouts to `email_backend=airflow.providers.sendgrid.utils.emailer` as seen [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/sendgrid/utils/emailer.py)